# R Leaflet doesn't add all markers

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to follow the example in the link below to create a map with all the markers

[Tutorial: How to put dots on a Leaflet map with R](http://trendct.org/2015/06/26/tutorial-how-to-put-dots-on-a-leaflet-map-with-r/)

The source file is below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/az1yolknqwoxhb4/test_file.csv?dl=0

And the code that I tried

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

test_map <- read.csv("test_file.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
m <- leaflet(test_map) %>% addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>') 
m %>% setView() 
m %>% addCircles(~long, ~lat, 
             popup=test_map$index, 
             weight = 3, 
             color="#ffa500", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8)
```

I was able to create the map

[image]

However, the map only shows a fraction of points, since the data I have has locations all over Canada. When I tried to sub-select a city say like Toronto then some of the missing points shows up.

I'm not sure if i'm doing anything wrong or if this is a bug.I wonder if there's anyway for me to fix this problem or is there an alternative way to achieve a similar map?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are NA values in test_map variable.

add

```
test_map <- na.omit(test_map)
```

after reading csv.

By this method i have more markers than your image.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine after removing the missing values. I didn't know that the na wouldn't get omitted by default.